# How to timeout on a slow streaming response body with Java's HttpClient

Tags: java, http, java-11, java-http-client

How should I deal with servers that hang sending an HTTP response body using the HTTP client included in Java 11 onwards, when I need to handle the response in a streaming fashion?

Having read the documentation, I'm aware that it's possible to set a [timeout on connection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html#connectTimeout(java.time.Duration)) and a [timeout on the request](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpRequest.Builder.html#timeout(java.time.Duration)):

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .build();

HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("http://example.com"))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .build();

HttpResponse<Stream<String>> httpResponse = httpClient
        .send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines());

Stream<String> responseLineStream = httpResponse.body();
responseLineStream.count();
```

In the above code:

- If a connection cannot be established within 2 seconds, a timeout exception will be thrown.
- If a response is not received within 5 seconds, a timeout exception will be thrown.  By experimentation, the timer starts after the connection is established, and for this type of `BodyHandler`, a response is considered received when the status line and headers have been received.

This means that when the code executes, within 7 seconds either an exception will have been thrown, or we'll have arrived at the last line.  However, the last line isn't constrained by any timeout.  If the server stops sending the response body, the last line blocks forever.

How can I prevent the last line hanging in this case?

Comment: Either the timeout applies only to the first read, or, more probably, it applies to all of them, such that if it expires during any read you will get the exception. The former is also possible but considerably less useful: in fact it would be poor design IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess this is left to the consumer of the stream, since this is part of the handling logic, so the body handling can be still be processed with a `CompletableFuture`:

```
HttpResponse<Stream<String>> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest,
                                                            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines());

Stream<String> responseLineStream = httpResponse.body();
CompletableFuture<Long> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> responseLineStream.count());
long count = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or just simply a `Future` executed by a Java [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Comment: I suspect this is the correct answer, but there's one thing I'm uncertain about.  I can wrap `future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` in a `try / finally` block, to ensure I close the `Stream` in the event of timeout or some other exception, but is this sufficient to avoid leaking resources?  In particular, I see the client socket in `CLOSE_WAIT`.  Is this just an inevitable consequence of a hung server, or is it an indication that the client left something undone?

Comment: Have you considered using https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.html#fromLineSubscriber(S,java.util.function.Function,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.lang.String) - that would allow you to cancel the subscription if data is not coming up in a timely manner.

Comment: Having stepped though the (OpenJDK 11.0.11) implementation, this is definitely the correct answer - the library code is designed to support the stream being closed while another thread is blocked waiting for the next element.  Be aware that when this happens, the blocking method (`responseLineStream.count()` in my example) will throw `java.io.UncheckedIOException`.  This is the same exception that gets thrown if, for example, the `content-length` header is incorrect, so you need to take care with your exception handling.

Comment: @daniel I *did* consider that, but I hoped there would be an easier way.

Comment: @MarkSlater Closing the stream might work - though  it wasn't designed to be called asynchronously from another thread. It should close the underlying `InputStream` which in turn should cancel the subscription, which should cause the resources to be (asynchronously) released.

Comment: See the `@apiNote` in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.html#ofLines(java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: How about the thread that is stuck hanging for a response? The thread that will be doing the CompletableFuture? If the count() hangs for X minutes then so will this thread. I'm not talking about the main thread here.

Answer (score 5):

One way to solve this is to set a timeout on the time taken to receive the whole body. That's what [M A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064245/m-a)'s solution does. As you've noticed, you should close the stream if timeout evaluates, so the connection is released properly instead of hanging in background. A more general approach is to implement a `BodySubscriber` that completes itself exceptionally when it is not completed by upstream within the timeout. This affords not having to spawn a thread just for timed waiting or close the stream. Here's an appropriate implementation.

```java
class TimeoutBodySubscriber<T> implements BodySubscriber<T> {
  private final BodySubscriber<T> downstream;
  private final Duration timeout;
  private Subscription subscription;

  /** Make sure downstream isn't called after we receive an onComplete or onError. */
  private boolean done;

  TimeoutBodySubscriber(BodySubscriber<T> downstream, Duration timeout) {
    this.downstream = downstream;
    this.timeout = timeout;
  }

  @Override
  public CompletionStage<T> getBody() {
    return downstream.getBody();
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
    this.subscription = requireNonNull(subscription);
    downstream.onSubscribe(subscription);

    // Schedule an error completion to be fired when timeout evaluates
    CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(timeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .execute(this::onTimeout);
  }

  private synchronized void onTimeout() {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      downstream.onError(new HttpTimeoutException("body completion timed out"));

      // Cancel subscription to release the connection, so it doesn't keep hanging in background
      subscription.cancel();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onNext(List<ByteBuffer> item) {
    if (!done) {
      downstream.onNext(item);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      downstream.onError(throwable);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void onComplete() {
    if (!done) {
      done = true;
      downstream.onComplete();
    }
  }

  static <T> BodyHandler<T> withBodyTimeout(BodyHandler<T> handler, Duration timeout) {
    return responseInfo -> new TimeoutBodySubscriber<>(handler.apply(responseInfo), timeout);
  }
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```java
Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
HttpResponse<Stream<String>> httpResponse = httpClient
        .send(httpRequest, TimeoutBodySubscriber.withTimeout(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines(), timeout));
```

Another approach is to use a read timeout. This is more flexible as the response isn't timed-out as long as the server remains active (i.e. keeps sending stuff). You'll need a `BodySubscriber` that completes itself exceptionally if it doesn't receive its next requested signal within the timeout. This is slightly more complex to implement. You can use [Methanol](https://mizosoft.github.io/methanol/) if you're fine with a dependency. It implements read timeouts as described.

```java
Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(3);
HttpResponse<Stream<String>> httpResponse = httpClient
    .send(httpRequest, MoreBodyHandlers.withReadTimeout(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines(), timeout));
```

Another strategy is to use a combination of both: time out as soon as the server becomes inactive or the body takes too long to complete.